# Overwriting/uploading an existing image via PHP every hour + changing directory correctly

Tags: php, image, directory, copy

I need to update a graphic on my FTP every hour. The "every hour" part is no problem, this would be done via cronjob(?) but I've some troubles with copying or uploading the image in the first place. Maybe my intinial thought how to solve this problem was wrong? I dunno...

So here is my code example:

```
<?php

    $ftp_server = "SERVERNAME";       
    $ftp_user = "USER";
    $ftp_pass = "PASSWORD";

    // set up a connection or die
    $conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

    // try to login
    if (@ftp_login($conn, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
        echo "Connected as $ftp_user@$ftp_server\n";
    } else {
        echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user\n";
    }

    echo "Current directory: ". ftp_pwd($conn) . "\n<br><br>";

    $file = "example.jpg";
    $newfile = "example.jpg";

    if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
        echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
    }
    ?>
```

The result is the following:

> Directory: /
>
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /user/usernumberxyz/subdomains/demo/test/countdown/example.php on line
>   47

I guess I have to set the directory right but I don't know how (but more because of my FTP enviroment).

I think this is where I need some help :-/

If I connect to my FTP via FileZilla the directory where my file is which I want to copy somewhere else is this: /demo/test/countdown

For opening a file in this directory I open it like this: http://subdomain.domain.com/demo/test/countdown/file.jpg

And as the error message shows, the directory is sth weird like this, too(?): /user/usernumberxyz/subdomains/demo/test/countdown/example.php

So I've tried several stuff for changing diectory with no success:

```
ftp_chdir($conn, '/demo/test/countdown');
ftp_chdir($conn, 'demo/test/countdown');
ftp_chdir($conn, '/user/usernumberxyz/subdomains/demo/test/countdown/');
ftp_chdir($conn, 'user/usernumberxyz/subdomains/demo/test/countdown/');
```

Evertime it results in: "Can't change directory".

Can anyone help me and is ftp_put or copy the right solution?

Comment: Why not put the upload,download part in cron as well and skip the php all together, it would be easy with the linux built in ftp command? http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ftp.htm

Answer (score 0):

First - you use copy() for copy on FTP? I think it's not good for remote ;)

Second - check permissions again, try change dir using ".." and write short test code for it. Example, code as above but just try only ftp_chdir() for ".." and check again current directory.

Third - yes, crontab will do this every hour

PS. Sorry for my english, I hope this is understand and my reply help you.

Comment: My current directory is "/" so moving backward with ".." won't change anything, right? 
But I've checked and it's still "/" :D
I just don't know how to move "forward"...